# PYTTSX Error: Cannot find module named drivers

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx

I am still a novice when it comes to python, and recently I have attempted to construct a personal assistant. I am using the PyTTSX module, but when I attempt to initialize the package, I receive this error:

****File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\driver.py", line 64, in **init**
    self._module = **import**(name, globals(), locals(), [driverName])
ImportError: No module named 'drivers**'**

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SAPI5 on Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7`

Comment: First install the pywin32-extensions package using its Windows installer. Then use pip to install pyttsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably downloaded the version of PyTTSX from the website, which was built for Python 2. The updated version can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/jpercent/pyttsx/tree/master/pyttsx). Copy the contents of pyttsx/pyttsx into your pythonXX/Lib/site-packages/pyttsx folder and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a python3 compatible version of pyttsx and is called **pyttsx3**

just use `pip install pyttsx3`

Its usage is almost same as that of pyttsx

```
import pyttsx3
engine  = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("hello")
engine.runAndWait()
```